# regEx match strings containing one l and three w

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to match those "<< match this" flagged strings in a short and easy way without making a tangled regEx with many `ORs` directly with regEx? Or using multiple regEx requests?

So the match should have 4 chars -> 3x w and 1x l

```
string = 
"wwww
lwlw
lwww  << match this
wlww  << match this
wwlw  << match this
wwwl  << match this
llll"
```

### Data:

```
string = 
"wwww
lwlw
lwww
wlww
wwlw
wwwl
llll"
```

### Output:

```
output = 
"lwww
wlww
wwlw
wwwl"
```

I believe in that case it seems best to go with the obvious. I was curious if there exists a shorter regex.

```
var str =
`wwww
lwlw
lwww
wlww
wwlw
wwwl
llll`;

str.match(/\bwlww\b|\blwww\b|\bwwlw\b|\bwwwl\b/g);

(4) ["lwww", "wlww", "wwlw", "wwwl"]
```

Comment: What is the expected output of this given string?

Comment: Split on newline. Extract lines by index.

Comment: This question is really about regEx tho. I think there are others functions in any language who can tackle the problem.

Comment: you can find the count of 'l' using  substr_count($text, 'l');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
(?=(?:.*w){3})(?=(?:.*l)).{4}
```

see [H E R E](https://regex101.com/r/3bzI6j/1)

Answer (score 2):

Filter it?

```js
var string = 
`wwww
lwlw
lwww
wlww
wwlw
wwwl
llll`;
var pattern = ["lwww","wlww","wwlw","wwwl"];

var vals = string.split(/\s/).filter(function(row) {
  row = row.trim();
  return pattern.indexOf(row)!=-1;
})
console.log(vals)
```

Without the array of patterns:

```js
var string = 
`wwww
lwlw
lwww
wlww
wwlw
wwwl
llll`;

var vals = string.split(/\s/).filter(function(row) {
  return "lwww"=== row.trim().split("").sort().join("");
})
console.log(vals)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with non-regex solution, then try `split` and `filter`

> So the match should have 4 chars -> 3x w and 1x l

You can check the `length` after replacing `l`'s and `w`'s.

`split` the data by *line-break* and then `filter` out those which doesn't match

```js
var str =
`wwww
lwlw
lwww
wlww
wwlw
wwwl
llll`;
//this function checks if the length of string after replace is equal to length
var replChLen = (str, ch, length) => 
    str.replace( new RegExp( ch, "g" ), "" ).length == length;

//filter out the matches
var output = str.split( "\n" ) //split by line-break
   .filter( s => //iterate to filter
      replChLen(s, "l", s.length - 1) //check if after replacing l, length is reduced by 1
        && replChLen(s, "w", s.length - 3) ); //check if after replacing w, length is reduced by 3
console.log( output );
```

Comment: I really think you went overboard with the one-liners here. It is really unreadable code. Imagine what a noob would think

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I realized the same, hope it is better now.

Comment: Unless there is a lot more behind the question, I think your functions and filters are a bit overkill ;)

Comment: @mplungjan I assumed that `lwwwabc` can also be valid as OP only mentioned *match should have 4 chars -> 3x w and 1x l*. Meaning, it can have other characters, just that these 2 are the matching criteria.